# Does the standard "Function Calling Sequence" described in Sys V ABI specs (both i386 and AMD64) apply to the static C functions?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, operating-system, abi

> In computer software, an application binary interface (ABI) is an interface between two binary program modules; often, one of these modules is a library or operating system facility, and the other is a program that is being run by a user.
>
> An ABI defines how data structures or computational routines are accessed in machine code, which is a low-level, hardware-dependent format; in contrast, an API defines this access in source code, which is a relatively high-level, relatively hardware-independent, often human-readable format. A common aspect of an ABI is the calling convention, which determines how data is provided as input to or read as output from computational routines; examples are the x86 calling conventions.
>
> -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

I am sure that the standard "Function Calling Sequence" described in Sys V ABI specs (both i386 and AMD64) constraints the calling of those extern functions in a C library, but does it constraints the calling of those static functions too?

Here is an example:

```
$cat abi.c

#include<stdio.h>
typedef void (*ret_function_t)(int,int);
ret_function_t gl_fp = NULL;
static void prnt(int i, int j){
    printf("hi from static prnt:%d:%d\n", i, j);
}
void api_1(int i){
    gl_fp = prnt;
    printf("hi from extern api_1:%d\n", i);
}
ret_function_t api_2(void){
    return gl_fp;
}

$cat abi_main.c

#include<stdio.h>
typedef void (*ret_function_t)(int,int);
extern void api_1(int i);
extern ret_function_t api_2(void);

int main(){
    api_1(1111);
    api_2()(2222, 3333);
}

$gcc abi_main.c abi.c -o abi_test

$./abi_test
hi from extern api_1:1111
hi from static prnt:2222:3333
```

The function calling sequence (including registers usage, stack frame, parameters passing, variable arguments...) details are defined in the Sys V ABI when abi_main.c call the api_1 and api_2 since they are extern, but what about the calling of the static function `prnt` which been defined in abi.c? Does it belong to the ABI standard or to the compiler to decide?

Comment: `static` functions are not subject of the ABI. The compiler might choose them not to exist at all but inline them, for example.

Comment: @Ctx What if the address of the function is taken and passed to code outside of the translation unit as a function pointer?

Comment: Hi Ctx, thank you very much for your reply. But what about the cases on the above code example? If the pointer of a static function being shared across C libraries and there would must be at least one copy of the un-inlined static function code, in this case does the ABI calling sequence standard applies to the static functions? If the answer is "no" and then there would be some problems when the code `api_2()(2222, 3333)` being executing.

Comment: In this case the compiler has to follow the ABI of course. However, this is not _generally_ true for static functions

Comment: @Ctx Then we could have such conclusion now: If we do not take the compiler's "inline" optimization into account (say it has been switched off), then the calling of the static functions has to follow the "calling sequence standard" defined in the ABI specs. So there would be a next question: Such compliance is defined by the ABI, OR just as a result of under the constraints by both the ABI and the C standard? Or even more, by the compiler's free will to decide any solution that as long as could satisfy both the ABI and the C standard?

Comment: @remus I would take a more minimalistic approach: If the function pointer is not taken anywhere in the object defining the static function, then it does not have to follow the ABI but can be optimized. I do not think, that this is explicitly stated somewhere, it is a pure consequence from that "it has to work". Exporting a function pointer to a static function and calling it from external is well-defined after all.

Comment: @Ctx "Exporting a function pointer to a static function and calling it from external is well-defined" -- But does the phrase "well-defined" in the C specs means -- calling such function pointers which pointing to static C functions are using the same calling convention defined in the ABI specs (as calling extern C functions does)? If answer is yes, then do you mind to give a detailed reference from certain spec? Also, there serveral more other situations about calling static functions.

Comment: @Ctx {To continue the above reply} -- For example: "calling a function pointer which is being returned from an extern function and the value of it pointing to a static function", and "calling function pointer which pointing to static function and such function pointer is as a member of a certain data structure instance" and etc.

Comment: @remus The ABI is out of scope of the C standard, it is merely an inevitable necessity to make object files, (dynamic and static) linking and using libraries work. The C standard specifies, that passing "pointers to static functions" and invoking these has to work. How exactly is unspecified, but it leads to ABIs and finally, that such static functions have to follow an ABI, otherwise it would _not_ work. Perhaps some C environment could come up with another concept than ABIs (but I couldn't really think of one)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do apply. Static functions are just plain functions with traslation-unit visibility. The ABI is a compiler generation task, C standard deliberately says nothing about it. It becomes clear when removing the `static` word from your code. The reasoning is the same. The *drawback* with this approach is that compiler cannot check the linkage right (caller-callee), but only its type (`void (*ret_function_t)(int,int);`) at compile time, since you are the one who links at runtime. So, it is not recommended.

What happens is that your compiler will generate code for any calling function, following some ABI, lets call it ABI-a. And it will generate code for 
a function being called according to some other ABI, lets say ABI-b. If *ABI-a == ABI-b*, that always work, and this is the case if you compile both files with the same ABI.

For example, this works if `prnt` function were located at address `0x12345678`:

```
ret_function_t gl_fp = (ret_function_t)0x12345678;
```

It also works as long as there is a function with the right arguments at `0x12345678`. As you can see, the function cannot be `inline`d because the compiler does not know which function definition will end up in that memory spot, there could be many.